# subir imágenes con angular para luego poder almacenarlas en BD

Tags: imagen

Necesito permitir al usuario de mi aplicación cargar una imagen y guardarla para luego, con laravel almacenarla en una base de datos.
No tengo ni idea de cómo empezar siquiera.
Alguna idea o ejemplo similar?
la imagen será parte de un objeto. Si la tengo en la BD soy capaz de mostrarla pero no sé cómo hacer el proceso inverso.
Muchas gracias